# Creating two document stores for same RavenDB application

Tags: ravendb

I have two applications that need to connect to a local raven db instance in a folder. The first application starts up fine. When the second application starts up, the document store cannot initialise because of file permissions.

How can I connect to the same database from multiple applications that both need their own document store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several instances (no matter if it's the same application or different applications) can't share the same database.

You can either use the standalone RavenDB server or make sure that each application instance opens it's own database.

If you are using the embedded version make sure that each instance get it's own data directory:

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory = "path/to/database/directory" };
```

documentStore.Initialize();

http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/connecting-to-a-ravendb-datastore

Comment: I want to modify data in the same database. Could you show me how to do that with the standalone server?

Comment: You need to run the ravendb server on a computer somewhere and then use one of the connection options in the document page that I linked to. Standalone server stragegies: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/deployment